# Best practices to code user level security in react.js

Tags: reactjs

New to react.js and was wondering if there are best practices that react devs are using to enforce user level security within the web application to show or hide elements within the virtual DOM using react.js?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you should never rely on hiding things on the client which are sensitive, any sensitive data should never be sent to an unauthorised client in the first place

Comment: @DominicTobias your point is valid: you don't want to send things that are sensitive to an unauthorized client. But that leaves the question unanswered of how or when to send the sensitive application code. Like an admin interface that could reveal too much information on how to use or abuse a system. Or an interface made for users with different roles. I would be interested in an answer. Multiple entry points? Is 'hot-loading' new parts of an application possible? Perhaps the question should be a little more verbose on how and what.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  That makes sense Dominic regarding sensitive data not being sent in the first place.  So that begs the question then in an SPA, should a roles based application have a seperate page (such as an Admin view as the stated example) based on the role of the user instead of coding for different roles access within a page?